# Javascript object has few values as arrays of length 1 how to make them not arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, coffeescript

I have a JS object which was created from an XML using xml2js library. The JS object has all elements as arrays with only one element in each array. How do I change it to only have the values without being inside the array.

For e.g. it looks like this: { a : [b], c : [d]} I want it to rather be like { a : b, c : d }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work on nested cases, you'll need to recurse through the structure:

```
undoTrivialArray = (obj) ->
  for own key of obj
    if _.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length == 1
      obj[key] = obj[key][0]
    else if _.isObject(obj[key])
      undoTrivialArray(obj[key])
```

Note that I used `isArray` and `isObject` from the underscore library.  This was mostly to keep it readable; those tests can be replaced by `{}.toString.call(obj[key]) == '[object Array]'` and `obj[key] == Object(obj[key])`, respectively (code taken from the underscore library).

Answer (score 4):

You can just transform the object:

```
function undoTrivialArrays( o ) {
  var k;

  for (k in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if ({}.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]' && o.length === 1)
        o[k] = o[k][0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or if you're sure that `o[k]` is an array and you're in CoffeeScript: `o[k] = o[k][0] for own k of o` or `o[k] = o[k][0] for k of o`.

Comment: will this work for nested cases as well? I tried but it does not seem to work. For e.g. it is {a:[{b:[c],d:[{e{:[f:[g]]}]}]} ?

Comment: @RuchirPatwa well if your object structure is complicated you may have to add more elaborate code to deal with deeply nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution if you prefer to use library:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

function undoTrivialArray(obj) {
    return _.object(_.keys(obj), _.values(_.flatten(obj)));
}
```

Comment: Even this does not seem to work in nested cases like {a:[{b:[c],d:[{e{:[f:[g]]}]}]} any solution to that?